# zend framework skeleton: why does the line require 'init_autoloader.php' work?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, require

In the 'public/index.php' file of ZF2 skeleton, there is the line :

```
Require 'init_autoloader.php'
```

the include_path before this line is : ".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear"

but this 'init_autoloader.php' file isn't in any directory of include_path (neither in 'public/', nor in '/usr/share/php', nor in '/usr/share/peer').

This file exists in the parent directory of 'public/'. But '..' is not in the include_path.

So, why does it work ?

Answer (score 3):

Because there is a change directory line at the top of the index.php file.

```
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
```

This changes the directory to it's parent where the file `init_autoloader.php` lives.  See [dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) and [chdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) for more info.